# Not Able to hit SOAP webservice locally run on Jboss4.0.3

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss, axis

I am trying to hit my local soap based web service, but I am not able to do it.

My jboss server log and application log does not have any error or exception . 
But I am getting exception on the client log, as follow.

**The exception trace is as follows**

```
com.tube.driverclient.DriverDataWebServiceSyncCallException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException 
    at com.tube.driverclient.DriverDataWebServiceSyncCall.invokeOneWay(DriverDataWebServiceSyncCall.java:59)
    at com.tube.driverwebservice.driver.DriverStub.sendDriverData(DriverStub.java:216)
    at com.tube.driverclient.DriverDataFeeder.send(DriverDataFeeder.java:109)
    at com.tube.driverclient.DriverDataUtil.sendPoints(DriverDataUtil.java:173)
    at com.tube.driverclient.DriverDataFeeder.main(DriverDataFeeder.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2939)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1727)
    at org.apache.axis.client.async.AsyncResult.run(AsyncResult.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the client code is not in sync with the server code.

Please try syncing the client with the server code.

Comment: The code is in sync, After the changing the log level , it seems that the client is not able to connect server and am getting following error in the log                                      "org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - Unable to get a connection, waiting..., hostConfig=HostConfiguration[host=http://localhost:8680" , Am able to hit the wsdl of the webservice through the browser but not able to connect with my client